# Handling Comma Separated Values in php

Tags: php, group-by

I am having a customer table in which there are three columns i.e customer_id,customer_name and customer_category and the customer_category is multiple for each customer and it is stored as comma separated in database.Now I want to make a report according to customer_category.How should I can do please help.

Comment: what you have tried yet??

Comment: for each customer I had exploded the customer_category and then in for loop used group_by clause but I am getting duplicate entries.

Comment: You should probably start with normalizing your database; storing multiple values as 1 value in your database leads to complications like the one you are facing now.

Comment: Ideally you need to have 2 more table, one to store category details and another one to map category to customer.

Comment: Don't abuse your database like this: it creates so many problems at all levels (highly-complex and inefficient code, slow database performance, etc), when it could all be made simple and efficient if you just normalized your datatables properly in the first place

Answer (score 0):

As per your question how to **handle with php**

$cus_record_set is customer record set from database .you can filter the customer based on category  .i just did example you can elaborate it by yourself

```
    <?php

      $cat1_cus =array();
      $cat2_cus =array();

     foreach($cus_record_set as $row){


      $multiple_cus_cat =  explode(',',$row['customer_category']);

       if(in_array("cat1", $multiple_cus_cat))
       {

           $cat1_cus[] =$row;
       }

       if(in_array("cat2", $multiple_cus_cat))
       {

            $cat2_cus[] =$row;
        }

     }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple loop, just explode customer category for each customer and again loop through each category and push the customer data into new array by grouping customer category like below

```
$customers = array(
                    0=>array('id'=>1,'name'=>'mani','customer_category'=>'cat1,cat2'),
                    1=>array('id'=>2,'name'=>'ravi','customer_category'=>'cat3,cat4'),
                    2=>array('id'=>3,'name'=>'rocky','customer_category'=>'cat2,cat3'),
                    3=>array('id'=>4,'name'=>'harry','customer_category'=>'cat1,cat4')
                   );
$categories = array();                 
foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    $catgs = explode(',',$customer['customer_category']);
    foreach($catgs as $catg)
    {
        $categories[$catg][] = $customer['name'];
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($categories);
```

This will give you something like this:

```
Array
(
    [cat1] => Array
        (
            [0] => mani
            [1] => harry
        )

    [cat2] => Array
        (
            [0] => mani
            [1] => rocky
        )

    [cat3] => Array
        (
            [0] => ravi
            [1] => rocky
        )

    [cat4] => Array
        (
            [0] => ravi
            [1] => harry
        )

)
```

I'm sure that you will understand this easily, if any question please ask and I prefer you to use a separate table for customer categories on the basis of customer id join both the tables and fetch records. This will make your webpage more reliable and efficient. Thank You.